# swift dynamic UIAlertController

Tags: swift, class, uialertcontroller

I try to create dynamic alert notifications, i want to use custom method in a class like this (setError : red background, setSuccess : green background,...) :

```
AlertHelpers.SetError("Error Password", viewController: self)
```

This is my code, i don't know if it's the good way :

```
class AlertHelpers {

    func notificationAlert(message:String, viewController : UIViewController) {

        //Create alert Controller _> title, message, style
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        //Create button Action -> title, style, action
        let successAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
            UIAlertAction in
            NSLog("OK Pressed")
        }

        alertController.addAction(successAction)

        viewController.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil)
    }
}

class SetError : AlertHelpers {
    override func notificationAlert(message:String, viewController : UIViewController) {}
    alertController.view.backgroundColor = .redColor() //RED BACKGROUND
}
```

alertController is not recognize and i can't find the solution to pass message and view through setError.

I begin in POO i don't understand how i can create subclass which inherit from a global class but customisable. If someone can explain me the good way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you can do is reading Apple's simple and elegant Swift documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/index.html).

To answer your question, this is one of the many approaches through which you can achieve your requirement:

```
class AlertHelper {

    private class func notificationAlert(message:String, viewController : UIViewController, color: UIColor) {

        //Create alert Controller _> title, message, style
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        // set the background color here
        alertController.view.backgroundColor = color

        //Create button Action -> title, style, action
        let successAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
            UIAlertAction in
            NSLog("OK Pressed")
        }

        alertController.addAction(successAction)

        viewController.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil)
    }

    class func displayError(message:String, viewController : UIViewController) {

        notificationAlert(message, viewController: viewController, color: .redColor())
    }

    class func displaySuccess(message:String, viewController : UIViewController) {

        notificationAlert(message, viewController: viewController, color: .greenColor())
    }
}
```